# Is it my application causing freezing and restarting the phone?

Tags: android

Recently some users of my application complaining that their phone freezes and restarts while using my app. My question is how can an App freeze Android OS? Is there a chance for that? If yes, what are the possible causes behind it? How can I isolate the issue?
(one of the user uses device SM-G900V, Android OS 5.0)

Comment: your app working on ui thread ?

Comment: Ask your user to provide dumpstate (logs). Once we have dumpstate, we can check the root cause

Comment: Duggu, yeah, some places i use runOnUiThread. @Kushal Where the user can get dumpstate logs?

Comment: I think you have some background threads which are keep running and is not killed after its usage, Check in debug mode how many threads are running.

Comment: @PreethiRao , Okay, let me ckeck that.

Comment: in Eclipse -> Top Right corner -> Click on DDMS -> goto Logcat and copy all logs when your app crashes

Comment: you take too much skipped frame, usually its because you run too many process in your UI thread

Comment: Sometimes it will be because of your app consuming to many threads, and once the limit reaches to threshold, the os will run of the threads that time the whole system freezes..

Comment: This is a ambiguous question. Many things can cause the device to restart. Specifically one way to do this is sometimes using hidden APIs and not handling them properly. Before we can even begin to help we need to know WHAT your app does. When the device starts entering this state you should be looking at the logs and seeing where the device is entering a bad state.

Comment: @PreethiRao , Hmm, that can happen with my application, since my application uses lot of thrads. And it even restarts the device?

Comment: Restarting i dont know, i had same problem of freezing , the number of thread used used go up gradually and never came down and when it reaches threshold the whole OS used freeze

Comment: @JoxTraex , I got your point. I wanted know if it's a problem with my application/an app can freeze entire OS and even restart it before looking for a solution.

Comment: @Manu this problem varies from device to device as well, I had nexus it used freeze after a while it would become proper.

Comment: @PreethiRao , Hmm, sounds quite similar to my issue. So how you dealt with it? How did you get the ongoing threads list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In debug mode i ran the my app and continuously used it, and found that thead count was not coming down and it was gradually increasing ,I noted the thread names. Then i used DDMS in that i used **update Thread** option and checked from where the thread was getting created. Actually in my case media related thread was not getting released(Its was system thread). Then i made sure that it gets released all time . Boom problem solved :)

Comment: Sounds Promising. . Hold on. Let me try that out. Wish me luck :)

Comment: Here is what i got, almost all the threads which are not getting released are belongs to External libraries I’m using. :-( Now how to release them?

Comment: You sure with the thread count increasing ? There must be some way to release them .. check for the methods in the library :)

Comment: Thanks for your persistence. :-) Yes, I see it increasing.  Do you remember the thread count you got that time? Just want to compare the numbers.

Comment: Not exactly but  i am sure that it varies from device to device.

Comment: @Manu Please accept the answer if it had helped you in solving your problem ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73153/discussion-between-manu-and-preethi-rao).